# Twin, cousin, and sexy prime property

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Why the digital root of twin primes is always $(2,4) (8,1) (5,7)$?

Why the digital root of two primes with difference $4$ is always $(4,8) (1,5) (7,2)$?

Comment: It's not possible for a prime to have units digit $4$ or $8$ (or $2$ or $5$ for that matter excluding $2$ and $5$ themselves). You also miss many case; for instance $11,13$ is a pair of twin primes with units digits $(1,3)$. Primes that differ by $4$ are not called sexy, and similar statements apply to them (e.g. $7-2$ is $5$, not $4$).

Comment: @anon He's talking about the digital root, not the units digit.

Comment: Its interesting that I had not heard that term before, huh.

Comment: For anyone who doesn't know, it's just the sum of all the digits, and if the sum greater than $10$, continually take the sum of the digits until the result is a single digit number. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their digital root has to differ by $2$ modulo $10$, because they are by definition separated by a difference of $2$. However, a prime number's digital root can never be $3$, $6$, or $9$, because in that case it would be divisible by $3$ (and therefore not prime). So that leaves only $\{1,2,4,5,7,8\}$, each coupled with a second number which is $n+2$ and is also in the set.

Apply the same reasoning to primes separated by $4$.

Comment: Thanks a million, pardon for the silly question>>

Answer (score 0):

the digital root of twin primes is NOT always (2,4)(8,1)(5,7).  The statement of the question should have excluded the twin primes (3, 5) where the digital roots are (3, 5)